# How do I show using cut points that these two subsets of the plane are not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

How do I show using cut points or cut pairs that these 2 subsets are not homeomorphic?

I cannot see any obvious cut points.

I see that, in the first diagram the only cut pairs of type 1 when 1 point is the end of the line segment not touching the circle and the other point is on the outer circle but not where the line and circle meet, and for the second the cut pairs of type one are any point on the inner ellipse not where it meets the line, and any point on the outer circle not where it meets the line. But surely these are both an infinite set of cut pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the set of noncut points. The first set has an isolated noncut point (the center of the circle), but that's not true in the second set.

Alternatively, the set of cutpoints of the second set is compact, but that fails for the first set.

Comment: referring to one of your more complicated solutions, is it true then that the subsets obtained by removal of cut-points of type 2 of two homeomorphic sets, are themselves homeomorphic?

Comment: @user3450230 No, why should that be true? Also, to clarify the terminology, noncut point = cut point of type 1 and cut point = cut point of type $\ge 2$, right?

Comment: @user3450230 yes thats what I mean. I cannot prove or disprove that these remaining subsets are homeomorphic but for some reason my intuition says they are. any contradiction would be helpful. also just to clarify I mean that the remaining subsets of say X are homeomorphic to the remaining subsets of say Y, not the 2 subsets of X  are homeomorphic to eachother

Comment: @user3450230 I have no idea what are you trying to say. But I just though of another simple solution, which I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct that these two spaces are not homeomorphic. If you are aware of the fundamental group of a space, the following might help, if you are not familiar (or aren't allow to use it) this might help your intuition.

For the space on the right, let's call it $Y$, if we remove a point on the interior of the "bridge" between the circles, the resulting space has two non-simply connected components, the two circles (plus a little tail thing sticking out of each). In contrast, the space $X$ on the left has no such points.